# how to plot graphs with different range in mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, piecewise

I am new to mathematica, how to remove the error in mathematica plots ,    I am attaching the mathematica codes, i want to plot the graph for different values of delta2 while delta1 varies from 0.02 to 0.1

```
    ClearAll;
    d1 = 0.2; d2 = 0.7; B = 1; B1 = 0.7; \[Beta] = 0.01; R1 = 
     exp (\[Beta]*B^2 (z - B1)); m = 1; k = 0.1;

    f[z_][\[Delta]2_] = 
      Piecewise[{{1, 
         0 <= z <= 
          d1}, {1 - (\[Delta]1/2)*(1 + Cos[2*(Pi/0.2)*(z - d1 - 0.1)]), 
         d1 <= z <= d1 + 0.2}, {1, 
         d1 + 0.2 <= z <= 
          B1 - 0.1}, {1 - (\[Delta]2/2)*(1 + Cos[2*(Pi/0.2)*(z - B1)]), 
         B1 - 0.1 <= z <= 
          B1}, {R1 - (\[Delta]2/2)*(1 + Cos[2*(Pi/0.2)*(z - B1)]), 
         B1 <= z <= B1 + 0.1}, {R1, B1 + 0.1 <= z <= B}}];
    A = -(m^2/4) - (1/4 k);
    S1[z_] = (f[z]^2/4*A) - ((1 + f[z]^2)/4*A)*Log[(A*f[z]^2) + 1];
    L22[\[Delta]2_] = Sum[(((-f[z]^6)/(6912*A)))/S1[z]*0.001, {z, 0, 1}];

    L2[\[Delta]2_] = L22[\[Delta]2]
    DP[\[Delta]1_, \[Delta]2_] = L2[\[Delta]2];
    Plot[{Dp[\[Delta]1, 0], Dp[\[Delta]1, 0.02], 
      Dp[\[Delta]1, 0.04]}, {\[Delta]2, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold]]
```

Comment: Hi, some advice: What error are you talking about? Can you also post the error message. Can you boil down your formulas to a minimal working example? I am quite sure that a one or two liner simplified version of `f[z]`will do the same trick.

Comment: Apart from that, I guess there are several issues in your code.

Comment: e.g. in `L22`what does the sum from 1 to 0.001 is supposed to do? and delta2 is never used in that function, while `f`should have two arguments, but you provide only one. I guess you should check carefully you function definitins and function calls first.

Comment: delta 1 ranges from 0 to 1 where as delta2=0, delta2=0.02, one curve with delta2=0, another curve with delta2=0.02,

Comment: can we add the sample image

Comment: ??? Sorry, but what are you trying to tell? Which image? You defined `f[z_][delta_]` but call `f[z]` only. So something is wrong there. Aslo `Sum[ ...,{z,1,0.001}]` does not make sense.

Comment: Can you edit and post the error message. Try to do some basic debugging as well. Try to make some manual function calls to see if each function does return what you expect, and each call works the way you use it.

Comment: sorry the z range from {z, 0, 1, 0.001}]

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. However, I really suggest that you clean up the thing and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Did you try the debugging? what does, e.g., `f[0.01]` return?

Comment: BTW, the sum looks like an approximation of an integral. What about `NIntegrate`?

Comment: sum in integration only

Comment: Can you be a bit more complete with your comments. It is very difficult to follow you / understand what you mean, not mentioning solving your problem.

Comment: please check it f[z] piecewise i have written with different interval  is correct or not and further  for different values of delta2 can we get the graphs or not and my codes are correct or not , if not please help me to write the correct codes

Comment: Well, the definition of `DP` doesn't do anything relevant nor does the definition of `L2`. The definitions of `L22` and `S` are probably wrong as `f` should be called with `z` and a `delta` argument. `f` itself is probably OK.

Comment: DP is nothing but L2[Delta2]                                                           DP[\[Delta]1_, \[Delta]2_] = L2[\[Delta]2]

Comment: Exactly, and `L2` is `L22`. So there is no point in having them here! Is your intention to confuse someone one purpose? Try to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you do not clean up this mess, I'd say there is no way helping you.

Comment: some changes i have done with the mathematica programme. My intention is how to plot the graphs when delta2 =0 to 0.01  for different delta 1 if f(z) is piecewise function

Comment: `Dp` is not defined. Did you mean `DP`?

Comment: It does not matter whether or `f` is picewise or not. The solution of plotting a set of continuous functions for a set of parameters is actually standard and quite easy. While I do not have Mathematica here to test and I am sort of stuck at Version 8 it was something like `Plot[ Evaluate[ Table[ f[t][param], {param, 0,.5,.01 } ] ], { t,0,1}]`. But as mentioned above, this will only help you if you get your function calls straight.

Comment: or simple: if you define `f[ z_][ delta_ ]` a call to `f[z]` does not make sense.